# Loading XML and csv files to datatables at startup

Tags: .net, xml, csv, vb.net

Here is some code that I put together for an app I am working on that loads 2 XML files and a large CVS file to a dataset at startup.  It runs fairly fast, but I would like a second opinion on what I could do to either make it more consise or faster.  I'm newer to .NET as well, so if you see anything that isn't very ."net ish" let me know!

```
#Region "Imports"

    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Xml
    Imports System.Text
    Imports System.Threading

#End Region


    Class clsLoadTables

#Region "Properties and Shared Variables"

    Private Shared pathTableTwo As String = My.Settings.pathTableTwo
    Private Shared pathMainTable As String = My.Settings.pathMainTable
    Private Shared pathBeneLifeExp As String = My.Settings.pathBeneLifeExp
    Private _ds As New DataSet
    Public Property ds() As DataSet
        Get
            Return _ds
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataSet)
            _ds = value
        End Set
    End Property

#End Region


#Region "Constructors"

    Sub New()

        loadBeneLifeExpTable()
        loadMainRMDTable()
        loadCSVTableII()

    End Sub

#End Region


#Region "ClassMethods"

    Public Sub loadCSVTableII()

        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables.Add("TableII")
        Dim line As String = String.Empty
        Dim counter As Short = 0
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(pathTableTwo)
        Dim errorString As New StringBuilder

        Try
            errorString.Append("The tableII csv file did not load properly")
            errorString.Append(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine)
            errorString.Append("Make syre the tabel_II.csv file is in the project folder")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

        Try
            While Not reader.EndOfStream()

                line = reader.ReadLine()
                Dim lineSep As List(Of String) = line.Split(",").ToList

                If Not counter = 0 Then
                    dt.Rows.Add(lineSep.ToArray)
                    counter += 1
                Else
                    For Each value As String In lineSep
                        dt.Columns.Add(value)
                    Next
                    counter += 1
                End If

            End While

            Dim primarykey(0) As DataColumn
            primarykey(0) = dt.Columns("Ages")
            dt.PrimaryKey = primarykey

        Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
            MessageBox.Show(errorString.ToString)
            Throw
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally
            reader.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub loadMainRMDTable()

        Dim tempDs As New DataSet 
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
        Dim errorString As New StringBuilder

        Try
            errorString.Append("The RMD table did not load properly!")
            errorString.Append(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine)
            errorString.Append("Make sure that the file 'MainRMDTable.xml' is in the project folder")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

        Try

            Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(pathMainTable, settings)

            tempDs.ReadXml(xmlFile)
            dt = tempDs.Tables("Age")
            dt.TableName = "MainRMDTable"

            xmlFile.Close()


            Dim primarykey(0) As DataColumn
            primarykey(0) = dt.Columns("age")
            dt.PrimaryKey = primarykey

            ds.Merge(tempDs)

        Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
            Throw
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(errorString.ToString)
            Throw
        Finally
            errorString.Clear()
            tempDs.Clear()
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub loadBeneLifeExpTable()

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
        Dim errorString As New StringBuilder

        Try
            errorString.Append("The bene life expectancy table did not load properly ")
            errorString.Append(Environment.NewLine & Environment.NewLine)
            errorString.Append("Make sure that the file 'beneLifeExpectancyTable.xml' is in the project folder")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try

        Try
            Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
            xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(pathBeneLifeExp, settings)

            ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
            dt = ds.Tables("Age")
            dt.TableName = "BeneLifeExpectancyTable"

            xmlFile.Close()

            Dim primarykey(0) As DataColumn
            primarykey(0) = dt.Columns("BeneLifeExpectancyTable")
            dt.PrimaryKey = primarykey

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(errorString.ToString)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & ex.StackTrace())
            Throw
        Finally
            errorString.Clear()
        End Try

    End Sub

#End Region

    End Class
```

Comment: I'm not a vb.net expert but do you need to do a line.ToList() on the string when you are doing a ToArray() later on.  Seems like possible duplication to me?

Comment: Dreza, yeah you are right.  The reason I did it this way is that I am trying to not use any of the vb array methods if I can get away with it.  I want to get in the habit of using the modern .Net components.  But in this case you are correct, I should just declare lineSep as an array becuase that is what line.split will return.  Also, since you can't add a generic list directly to a datatable I could eliminate the dt.row.Add(lineSep.ToArray) statement as well.  Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move code that displays Message Boxes up the call hierarchy.
Make better use of exceptions.
Use String Builders only when you append a lot, not just a couple of lines, try using String.Format.
Follow official VB.NET naming conventions "Begin each separate word in a name with a capital letter".

Make one generic method instead of loadMainRMDTable and loadBeneLifeExpTable by passing file path, table name and column name(s) as parameters.

Some code to illustrate:

```
Sub New()
    Try
        LoadBeneLifeExpTable()
        LoadMainRMDTable()
        LoadCSVTableII()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub


Public Sub LoadBeneLifeExpTable()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings

    Try
        Dim xmlFile As XmlReader
        xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(pathBeneLifeExp, settings)

        ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)
        dt = ds.Tables("Age")
        dt.TableName = "BeneLifeExpectancyTable"

        xmlFile.Close()

        Dim primarykey(0) As DataColumn
        primarykey(0) = dt.Columns("BeneLifeExpectancyTable")
        dt.PrimaryKey = primarykey

        Catch ex As Exception
            //' Using String.Format would be even better
            Throw New Exception("The bene life expectancy table did not load properly " + _
                        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + _
                        "Make sure that the file '" +  "' is in the project folder",
                        ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

PS: try not to use VB(.NET) - there are better languages; get ReSharper (it will give you some hints on how to make code better).

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. When I use just the 'throw' statement in my methods it is because the class that is calling the methods is already using a try statement.  I thought that I had to do it this way to retain the ex.stacktrace all the way up the code.  I've been looking around for some good vb.net documentation about nested exceptions but cannot find any.  Do you know of any good links?  BTW - I am using VB.Net because I have to for a few projects at work.  I fully intend on getting up to speed with C# once I can write basic apps in vbnet.

Comment: "Nested exceptions" is probably not a widely recognized term and there is not much to it. You are correct that "Throw" allows you to preserve the stack trace as opposed to "Throw ex". However you can also set ex.InnerException property as I did via constructor to specify the underlying exception that caused current exception. This way you can build a "hierarchy" of exceptions - e.g. from more concrete to more generic. When using ex.ToString() it will produce a string containing messages and stack traces of current exception along with all its inner exceptions. It's OOP - not a language feature